# Getting multiple legends from for loop with specific data column and row as legend title

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, legend

I have a plot that iterates through different databases in a list. However, I of course want to know which database is what graph. The databases don't have a title. So I was thinking of using a specific point from a column / row. Which makes it clear for me what database I am seeing.

Inorder to extract a specific float from a column / row which is contained in my list of databases,

I use: `specific_float = list_of_databases[list_index][database_column_name][database_index]`

The same principle I would like to use for my for loop with plots. So I was thinking of something like this:

Some context about the names in the code:

- dc_oppervlakte_filter is the list with dataframes
- TP_TARGET is an column name from the dataframes
- TP_SMOTE same story as TP_TARGET
- STRIP_WIDTH is the column I want to use for my legend with index 0

```
for k in dc_oppervlakte_filter:
    plt.plot(k['TP_TARGET'], k['TP_SMOTE'], 'o', label = k['STRIP_WIDTH'][0])
plt.xlabel("TP_TARGET in ($\u00b0C$)")
plt.ylabel("TP_SMOTE in ($\u00b0C$)")
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
```

However, this gives me the error: Keyerror: 0

So I tried:

```
for k in dc_oppervlakte_filter:
    plt.plot(k['TP_TARGET'], k['TP_SMOTE'], 'o', label = dc_oppervlakte_filter[k]['STRIP_WIDTH'][0])
plt.xlabel("TP_TARGET in ($\u00b0C$)")
plt.ylabel("TP_SMOTE in ($\u00b0C$)")
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
```

But it gives me the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFrame

An optimal scenario for me would look like that there's an legend with the specific float chosen from every database that's used to plot a graph.

Comment: We should know what `dc_oppervlakte_filter` is to help you. It seems to be a list of dataframes, but we don't know what type of dataframe.

Comment: So from `k['STRIP_WIDTH'][0]`, I guess "STRIP_WIDTH" is a column, and you want the first cell in that column (which should be a text cell; width suggests a number though). But since [0] doesn't exist, that means the indices of your dataframe don't start at 0; probably because they were retrieved from the database, which may start at 1, or any unique value.

Comment: Try `str(k['STRIP_WIDTH'].iloc[0])`.

Comment: @9769953 I edited the page with some context. Hopefully this helps. Yes, I would like the legend title to be a number instead of text. Maybe concert the number to string? I've tried replacing the [0] with [1] but still the same error in both scenario's.

Comment: @9769953 I've tried your ```str(k['STRIP_WIDTH'].iloc[0])``` but it didn't work. It gave me the error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Out of bounds? Then the respective dataframe is empty.

Comment: @9769953 I've checked the k dataframe and it's indeed empty. Just wondering why it would use a filled dataframe at ```k['TP_TARGET'], k['TP_SMOTE']``` for my x and y values but won't show a filled dataframe for my legend. Maybe because the legend can only see strings intead of floats?

Comment: It doesn't: the other two columns will also be empty. Print the empty dataframe in the line above the `plt.plot` call to see that.